# ASP.NET Identity with dapper and autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, autofac

I am trying to create a new ASP.NET application that uses ASP.NET Identity for authentication combined with autofac and Dapper. I know that I have to combine these 2 projects https://github.com/whisperdancer/AspNet.Identity.Dapper and https://developingsoftware.com/configuring-autofac-to-work-with-the-aspnet-identity-framework-in-mvc-5/ 
but I don't know how to do it.

**Update 1:**
I am not going to copy all of the code as it exists on the previous links.
I am using the Repository Pattern like this

```
public class Repository : DataConnection, IRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    public Repository(IDbConnection connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return Connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> objFunc) where T : new()
    {

        // Orm Lite Version 
        return Connection.Select<T>(objFunc);


    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> Dictionary<K, V>(string cacheKey, string Sql)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> items = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as Dictionary<int, string>;
        if (items == null || !items.Any())
        {
            items = Connection.Dictionary<int, string>(Sql);
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, items, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120));

        }
        return items;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> Dictionary<K, V>(string Sql)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> items;
        items = Connection.Dictionary<int, string>(Sql);
        return items;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryString<K, V>(string Sql)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> items;
        items = Connection.Dictionary<string, string>(Sql);
        return items;
    }


    public Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryString<K, V>(string cacheKey, string Sql)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> items = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as Dictionary<string, string>;
        if (items == null || !items.Any())
        {
            items = Connection.Dictionary<string, string>(Sql);
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, items, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120));

        }
        return items;
    }

    public IList<T> Select<T>(string cacheKey, string Sql, object filter) where T : new()
    {
        IList<T> items = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as IList<T>;
        if (items == null || !items.Any())
        {
            items = Connection.Select<T>(Sql, filter);
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, items, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120));
        }

        return items;

    }

    //where T : new(); has been omitted here as this function returns int, string etc
    public T ExecuteScalar<T>(string Sql, object filter)
    {
        return Connection.ScalarFmt<T>(Sql, filter); 
    }

    public IList<T> Select<T>(string Sql, object filter) 
    {
        IList<T> items;
        items = Connection.Select<T>(Sql, filter);
        return items;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : new()
    {
        // Orm Lite Version 
        return Connection.LoadSelect<T>();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="filters"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T GetFirst<T>(string cacheKey, object filters) where T : new()
    {
        T item = (T)MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey);
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = Connection.SingleById<T>(filters);
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120));

        }
        // OrmLite Version
        return item;

    }

    public T GetFirst<T>(object filters) where T : new()
    {
        T item = Connection.SingleById<T>(filters);
        return item;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="instance"></param>
    public long Add<T>(T instance) where T : new()
    {
        //Ormlite Version 
        //Connection.Save(instance);
        var Id = Connection.Insert(instance, selectIdentity: true);
        return Id;

    }


    public void Update<T>(T instance) where T : new()
    {
        //OrmLite version
        Connection.Update(instance);
    }

    public void Delete<T>(object filters) where T : new()
    {
        Connection.DeleteById<T>(filters);

    }

}
```

where DataConnection Class is like this

```
public class DataConnection : IDisposable
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IDbConnection _connection;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    protected IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Connecting)
                _connection.Open();

            return _connection;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    public DataConnection(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public DataConnection(string connString)
    {
        if (connString == "")
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name;

        _connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close the connection if this is open
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _connection.Close();
            //not sure if this line is needed
            _connection.Dispose();
        }
        //the same for the following line
        _connection = null;
    }
}
```

The initial configuration of Autofac is being done in 2 places. In a class named IoC like this

```
public class IoC : ContainerBuilder 
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private readonly static IoC _instance = new IoC();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private static object _lock;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IContainer _componentsContainer;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static IoC Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IContainer GetComponentsContainer()
    {
        if (_componentsContainer == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_componentsContainer == null)
                    _componentsContainer = this.Build();
            }
        }

        return _componentsContainer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().BeginLifetimeScope();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IoC()
    {
        _lock = new object();
        ConfigureDependencies();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void ConfigureDependencies()
    {
        //Configure all your depedendencies here!!

        //Database connection
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
        this.Register(c => new SqlConnection(connectionString)).As<IDbConnection>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        //Database Connection OrmLite
        OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqlServerDialect.Provider;
        //Repository
        this.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();


        this.RegisterType<ApplicationUserStore>().As<IUserStore<AppMember,int>>().InstancePerRequest();

        this.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        this.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        this.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerRequest();

    }

}
```

and in ConfigureAuth method of StartUp Class like this

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {


        //IDataProtectionProvider has to be resolved here as it's the only place where IAppBuilder is available
        IoC.Instance.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login")
        });

    }
}
```

My ApplicationUserStore Class derives from a custom UserSrore Class like this

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<AppMember>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

where UserStore is like this

```
public class UserStore<TUser> : IUserLoginStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserClaimStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserRoleStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser, int>,
    IQueryableUserStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserEmailStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserLockoutStore<TUser, int>,
    IUserStore<TUser, int>
    where TUser : IdentityMember
{
    private UserTable<TUser> userTable;
    private RoleTable roleTable;
    private UserRolesTable userRolesTable;
    // This ASP.NET Identity implemantaion won't use claims
    private UserClaimsTable userClaimsTable;
    private UserLoginsTable userLoginsTable;
    private IRepository Repository;

    public IQueryable<TUser> Users
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public UserStore()
    {
        IRepository repository = IoC.Instance.Resolve<IRepository>();
        new UserStore<TUser>(repository);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that takes a dbmanager as argument 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="database"></param>
    public UserStore(IRepository repository)
    {

        this.Repository = repository;
        userTable = new UserTable<TUser>(repository);
        roleTable = new RoleTable(repository);
        userRolesTable = new UserRolesTable(repository);
        //Claims are not implemented
        userClaimsTable = new UserClaimsTable(repository);
        userLoginsTable = new UserLoginsTable(repository);
    }
```

There is no reason to write all the methods that the UserStore class has, but it is sure that I make a configuration error in Autofac cause this function

```
public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Null or empty argument: userName");
        }

        List<TUser> result = userTable.GetUserByName(userName) as List<TUser>;

        // Should I throw if > 1 user?
        if (result != null && result.Count == 1)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<TUser>(result[0]);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<TUser>(null);
    }
```

fails with a null reference error. UserTable is not initialised.

**Update 2:**

UserTable Class

```
public class UserTable<TUser>
    where TUser : IdentityMember
{
    private IRepository Repository;
    public UserTable(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }
```

And IdentityMember Class is custom as well, as follows

```
 public class IdentityMember : IUser<int>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor 
    /// </summary>
    public IdentityMember()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that takes user name as argument
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    public IdentityMember(string userName)
        : this()
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// User ID
    /// </summary>
    [Alias("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User's name
    /// </summary>
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Email
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     True if the email is confirmed, default is false
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The salted/hashed form of the user password
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     A random value that should change whenever a users credentials have changed (password changed, login removed)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     PhoneNumber for the user
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     True if the phone number is confirmed, default is false
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Is two factor enabled for the user
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     DateTime in UTC when lockout ends, any time in the past is considered not locked out.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Is lockout enabled for this user
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Used to record failures for the purposes of lockout
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }




}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid your question must be more concrete to be answerable. What have you tried and what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I updated my question with more details.

Comment: If `userTable` is null, how does it get initialised? is `Repository` in constructor injected correctly?

Comment: I Updated my question, adding UserTable Class.

Comment: Can't see how `UserTable` can be `null`, as it is directly initialised and given a repository. I suspect repository is not injected into `UserStore`, but I can't see how you resolve classes.

Comment: I believe this is my problem. How to resolve classes. This is my problem. How UserStore and UserTable should be registered and resolved